# editing bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am currently learning the ropes with web development and have started using Bootstrap, I am currently working on the carousel. I don't like the design and I have found [an alternative carousel](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/)

I have tried a number of ways and I have read the guide on the website but for some reason I cannot make it work on my website. Does anyone know how I would go about adding the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to get you started:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/hV3bT/

I downloaded the zip package from http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/ and then checked out the basic.htm page.

If you look at the HTML of the bootstrap example it is almost exactly the same as this downloaded sample page, except instead of putting the content inside the

```
<div class="fluid_container"> ... </div>
```

I put it inside the equivalent bootstrap grid

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">

<!-- content here -->

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I then loaded the CSS and javascript files in the same order as they are in the basic.html example.

I think the only other thing is that you will notice the example page also has some styles in the head. Probably the only one you need is the #back_to_camera div.

If you need more info on the CSS and javascript in this example, go to the jsFiddle and check the source code of the results pane. You will see which CSS and javascript files are being used, the order they are loaded as well as the additional CSS and javascript in the head.

My example is missing a few icons ... arrowheads and the like. Once you install the images, javascript and CSS on your site I think they should all be good as well.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: I have added this extra CSS to force the thumbnails at the bottom of the second carousel example to display horizontally

```
.camera_thumbs_cont ul{
width:100% !important;
}

.camera_thumbs_cont li
{
display: inline !important;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```